# How to replace Null values in open CSV using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV open under read. I have noticed there are some blank data and I want to replace them with 0 instead of null. What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking of using an if none statement. If I use this, could I add a write function under this statement and can I add a write to csv function within a read csv function?

Main code-

````
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    print('File has been imported')
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    
    Cumlative_Cases_Total=0
    Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed=0 
    probabal=0 
    
    tracker=0

    
    
    for line in csv_reader:
        
        get_id=int(line[0])
        new_case=int(line[12])
        prob=int(line[5])
        
        #recovered=int(line[9])
        
        #print(get_id)
        #print(new_case)
        
        if get_id == 1 :
            Cumlative_Cases_Total = Cumlative_Cases_Total + new_case + prob
            Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed=Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed+new_case
            probabal=probabal+prob
            
            confirmed_array.append(Cumlative_Cases_Confirmed)
            total_array.append(Cumlative_Cases_Total)
            
            tracker= tracker+1 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pandas?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

print(df1.fillna('0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I would recommend using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
df.fillna(0)
```